# How do I get rid of flicker with STM_SETIMAGE

Tags: winapi, bitmap, flicker

We have updated our windows code to use Styles and since then we get a flicker in various parts of the code when using STM_SETIMAGE to update a bitmap on a window.

I have created a minimal reproducible example here. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get rid of the flicker please ?

The code simply redraws a bitmap every 1/100 second and calls the windows function to set the image onto the window. It worked without a flicker before we added Windows Styles.

Thanks

Shaun

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <objbase.h>


#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

//--------------------------------------

#ifndef HINST_THISCOMPONENT
EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#define HINST_THISCOMPONENT ((HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase)
#endif

//--------------------------------------

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

//--------------------------------------

HWND logo;
HWND m_hwnd;
HBITMAP testBitmap;
int counter=0;

typedef unsigned char u8;
typedef unsigned int u32;

//--------------------------------------

HRESULT App_Initialize()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    // Register the window class.
    WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
    wcex.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra    = sizeof(LONG_PTR);
    wcex.hInstance     = HINST_THISCOMPONENT;
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);;
    wcex.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.lpszClassName = TEXT("myApp");

    RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    int dpiX = 0;
    int dpiY = 0;
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (hdc)
    {
        dpiX = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
        dpiY = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
       ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    }

    m_hwnd = CreateWindow( TEXT("myApp"), TEXT("Simple Set image Example"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 640, 640, NULL,NULL,HINST_THISCOMPONENT,0);

    hr = m_hwnd ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);
    }

    logo = CreateWindow("Static", NULL, SS_BITMAP |  WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 40, 40,512,512, m_hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  
    return hr;
}

//----------------------------------------------

void    Redraw()
{
    DeleteObject(testBitmap);
    testBitmap=0;

    u8 * RenderImageData=(u8*)malloc(512*512*4);
    u32 * p=(u32*)RenderImageData;

    for(int i=0;i<512;i++)
    {
        p[i+counter*512]=0xff000000;
        p[i*512+counter]=0xff000000;
    }

    testBitmap = CreateBitmap(512,512, 4, 8, RenderImageData);
    SendMessage(logo,STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) testBitmap);
    free(RenderImageData);
    counter=(counter+1)&511;
}

//----------------------------------------------

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance ,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance ,LPSTR lpCmdLine ,int nCmdShow)
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(CoInitialize(NULL)))
    {
        if (SUCCEEDED(App_Initialize()))
        {
            MSG msg;
            while(1)
            {
                while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0,0,PM_REMOVE))
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }   
                Sleep(10);
                Redraw();
            }
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}

//----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: A control parent should practically always specify the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` [window style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles).

Comment: I have edited the code as some lines were missing, but I added WS_CLIPCHILDREN in here and it made no difference...   m_hwnd = CreateWindow( TEXT("myApp"), TEXT("Simple Set image Example"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,  640, 640, NULL,NULL,HINST_THISCOMPONENT,0);

Comment: You're forcing an update outside `WM_PAINT` handling. That's usually not a recipe for success. You're also leaking bitmap handles, so that's not going to run for long anyway. Is this the actual code you're using?

Comment: I set up a minimum example so I could post it here, but the 'delete bitmap, create bitmap from data, send message (STM_SETIMAGE ) loop' is used throughout the code. It simply doesnt flicker without Windows Styles which we only enabled recently. I thought I had freed the bitmap handle at the start of the Redraw function.

The idea is that it can be updated constantly on a timer to animate, or just when we know there has been a change. Should we be sending a WM_PAINT command and then doing the "redraw" code when WM_PAINT is handled ?

Comment: I see that you're deleting the bitmap now, but you're doing it while it's still owned by the static control. That's a bug. You'll want to delete the image that's returned from sending the `STM_SETIMAGE` message (although [things are actually a bit more complicated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140219-00/?p=1713) than that).

Comment: I added code to delete the secret copy, but it still flickers. Only with the styles pragma line enabled.. And it flickers whether or not I call DeleteObject at the start of Redraw(). Seems that the windows code handling the styles is conflicting with setting the image.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code which seems to work.

Instead of

```
HBITMAP hbm=(HBITMAP)SendMessage(hWndPic,STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) pD->hbitmap);
```

I call

```
GDI_SetImageX(pD->hbitmap,hWndPic, xs, ys);


void GDI_SetImageX( HBITMAP hBM, HWND hCtrl , int w, int h) 
{ 
    HDC hdcSrc=CreateCompatibleDC(0);                                           
    HDC hdcDst=GetDC(hCtrl);                                                    
    
    HGDIOBJ hbmOld=SelectObject(hdcSrc,hBM);                                    
    HGDIOBJ hbmNew=CreateBitmap(w,h,4,8,0);                                     
    HGDIOBJ hbmOld2=SelectObject(hdcDst,hbmNew);                                
    BitBlt(hdcDst,0,0,w,h,hdcSrc,0,0,0x00cc0020);                               
    SelectObject(hdcSrc,hbmOld);                                                
    DeleteDC(hdcSrc);                                                           
    ReleaseDC(hCtrl,hdcDst);                                                    

    SendMessage(hCtrl,0x0b,0,0);                                                
    LRESULT oBM=SendMessage(hCtrl,STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM) hBM);    
    SendMessage(hCtrl,0x0b,1,0);                                                
    DeleteObject(hBM);                                                          
}
```